# Not Getting Correct Info from Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, plist, mbcalendarkit

I am using MBCalendarKit and have it working but I'm trying to use the info dictionary for each event I've created to display the details on a detail page after selecting an event in the calendar view. My events are all created from a plist file:

[image]

Here is where I create the events:

```
// Read Events.plist

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Events" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictPri = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *arrEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictPri objectForKey:@"List"]];

    // Loop through each item in List array of Events.plist

    for (NSDictionary *dict in arrEvents)
    {
        NSString *titleString = nil;
        NSString *date = nil;

        titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Title"]];
        date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Date"]];

        // Create events

        aCKCalendarEvent = [[CKCalendarEvent alloc] init];
        aCKCalendarEvent.title = titleString;
        aCKCalendarEvent.date = [dateformatter dateFromString: date];
        aCKCalendarEvent.info = [dict objectForKey:@"Info"];

        _information = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aCKCalendarEvent.info];

        BOOL dateExists;

        for (int i = 0; i < [eventsArray count]; i++)
        {
            if ([[(CKCalendarEvent *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:i]date]isEqualToDate:aCKCalendarEvent.date])
            {
                // Array already contains object with this date

                dateExists = YES;
            }
            else
            {
                dateExists = NO;
            }

            NSLog(@"%c", dateExists);
        }

        if (dateExists == YES)
        {
            [eventsArray addObject:aCKCalendarEvent];
            [_eventsDict setObject:eventsArray forKey:aCKCalendarEvent.date];
        }
        else
        {
            eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [eventsArray addObject:aCKCalendarEvent];
            [_eventsDict setObject:eventsArray forKey:aCKCalendarEvent.date];
        }
    }
```

And here is the code for what happens when selecting an event:

```
- (void)calendarView:(CKCalendarView *)CalendarView didSelectEvent:(CKCalendarEvent *)event;
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    EventDetail *detail = [[EventDetail alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    detail.details = _information;
    detail.eventTitle = event.title;
    detail.eventDate = [dateformatter stringFromDate:event.date];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

My problem is that the details shown on the detail view is always the detail info of the last event in the plist file so no matter which event is selected, the details always say San Antonio, TX.

**I have changed `detail.details = _information;` to be `detail.details = [event.info objectForKey:@"Info"];`  However, that causes `-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbcc2000`**

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing a bit of the `- (void)calendarView:(CKCalendarView *)CalendarView didSelectEvent:(CKCalendarEvent *)event;` method.

Here is the working code for selecting an event:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    EventDetail *detail = [[EventDetail alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    _information = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", event.info];

    detail.details = _information;
    detail.eventTitle = event.title;
    detail.eventDate = [dateformatter stringFromDate:event.date];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```